# Add a Row title to a csv Export in php Symfony

Tags: php

I have the following function below that fully downloads the call into a csv file.  All I am trying to do is add a header title, can anyone see where I can put that in?

```
public function downloadCsv()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(CustomerSales::class);
        $totalRevenue = $em->totalRevenue();


        $rows = [];
            foreach ($totalRevenue as $total){
                $data = [
                   $total['total_sales']
                ];


                $rows[] = implode(',', $data);
            }

            $content = implode("\n", $rows);

            $response = new Response($content);
            $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
            return $response;
    }
```

Comment: Just FYI: There is `fputcsv` which also works with a temporary stream, since you do not want to save to an actual file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before your `foreach` you could just do:

```
$rows[] = implode(',', ['total_sales']);
```

or how many header columns you got ...

Comment: so, something like this?

`$rows[] = implode(',', ['D_Id', 'Customer_Name' ,'Customer_Number' ,'Dealer_Name' ,'Total_Sales');`

Comment: That worked (didnt want to add a library just for this.  Thanks!